# ArcObjects event when ArcMap table of contents selection is changed

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I have been trying to figure this out for almost a full working day and I just can't get it working. All I want to do is fire an event when the user clicks different layers in the ArcMap table of contents.

I can get it working with, for example, the PageLayout using this:

```
IActiveViewEvents_Event pageLayoutEvent = ArcMap.Document.PageLayout as IActiveViewEvents_Event;
```

I have Googled and looked into a bunch of different threads, all revolving around the concept of 'IActiveViewEvents_Event'interfaces. I've been able to get the event when the selection changes within the map document itself but I cannot get an event to fire in the Table of Contents.

My best attempt looks like this:

```
IActiveViewEvents toc = ArcMap.Document.get_ContentsView(0) as IActiveViewEvents;
IActiveViewEvents_Event tocEvent = ((TOCCatalogView)toc).SelectedItem as IActiveViewEvents_Event;
```

However tocEvent is set to null. If I do not cast to IActiveViewEvents_Event, SelectedItem is not null...

Can you provide a full example of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question: [Event raised when selected layer changes in TOC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3685/event-raised-when-selected-layer-changes-in-toc), but it will unfortunately not be good news for you, as no event of such kind is available in ArcObjects. The answers will provide some hack-ish workarounds which you may find useful.